# Unable to log exception into a table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

System Exception can only be propagated. Unable to log exception into a table, only it can be logged into log file/server log in postgresql.

Comment: Are you using psql?  A code example and your environment would be helpful in understanding your issue

Answer (score 2):

When you perform a `ROLLBACK`, *all* changes to the database by that transaction are undone, even those to your logging table.

The solution is to use [savepoints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-transactions.html).

If you write SQL outside a PostgreSQL function, use [`SAVEPOINT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-savepoint.html) and [`ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-rollback-to.html).

If you are writing a [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) function, use the [`EXCEPTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) clause of a `BEGIN ... END` block to continue processing after an exception.