# Inserting into a Table, Returning Different Data in Exception Block in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, exception

I need to write a function that obeys the following rules:

1. When an exception is thrown, insert exception info into an error log table
2. Either:

   - Raise an exception while preventing the error log insertion from rolling back
   - Raise a notice and return all nulls

Successful insertion inserts into the table and returns the data that was passed in.  I  need to return the values that were inserted to the function because the caller is an ORM app.  My choice is to either return what was passed in or force the calling program to read the table for what was passed in.  I feel this solution is better because it prevents an unnecessary read from the table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.error_log (
  func_name TEXT,
  dt_error TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT NOW(),
  stacked_dx JSONB
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.my_table (
  col1 TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  col2 INT,
  col3 TEXT,
  dt_inserted TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.uf_test (
  in_col1 TEXT,
  in_col2 INT DEFAULT NULL::INT,
  in_col3 TEXT DEFAULT NULL::TEXT
)
RETURNS TABLE (
  out_col1 TEXT,
  out_col2 INT,
  out_col3 TEXT
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$
  DECLARE
    ret_sql_state TEXT;
    col_name TEXT;
    constraint_nm TEXT;
    pg_datatype_nm TEXT;
    msg_text TEXT;
    tbl_name TEXT;
    sch_name TEXT;
    pg_exc_detail TEXT;
    pg_exc_hint TEXT;
    pg_exc_contxt TEXT;

    func_name TEXT := 'uf_test';
    arg_list JSONB;
    jsonb_msg JSONB;

  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO public.my_table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES
      (in_col1, in_col2, in_col3);

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    BEGIN
      GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS
        ret_sql_state = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
        col_name = COLUMN_NAME,
        constraint_nm = CONSTRAINT_NAME,
        pg_datatype_nm = PG_DATATYPE_NAME,
        msg_text = MESSAGE_TEXT,
        tbl_name = TABLE_NAME,
        sch_name = SCHEMA_NAME,
        pg_exc_detail = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL,
        pg_exc_hint = PG_EXCEPTION_HINT,
        pg_exc_contxt = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;

      arg_list := JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT (
        'in_col1', in_col1,
        'in_col2', in_col2,
        'in_col3', in_col3
      );

      jsonb_msg := JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT (
        'RETURNED_SQLSTATE', ret_sql_state,
        'COLUMN_NAME', col_name,
        'CONSTRAINT_NAME', constraint_nm,
        'PG_DATATYPE_NAME', pg_datatype_nm,
        'MESSAGE_TEXT', msg_text,
        'TABLE_NAME', tbl_name,
        'SCHEMA_NAME', sch_name,
        'PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL', pg_exc_detail,
        'PG_EXCEPTION_HINT', pg_exc_hint,
        'PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT', pg_exc_contxt,
        'Func-Proc', func_name,
        'Arguments', arg_list
      );

      INSERT INTO public.error_log (func_name, stacked_dx)
      SELECT func_name, jsonb_msg;

      RETURN QUERY
        SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL;

      RAISE NOTICE 'ERROR: %s\nCONTEXT: %s\nSQL state: %s', msg_text, pg_exc_contxt, ret_sql_state;
    END;

    RETURN QUERY
      SELECT in_col1, in_col2, in_col3;
    RETURN;
  END;
$function$
;
```

Attempted:

- RETURN QUERY (with values passed in) before the exception block, I always get those values.
- If I have RETURN QUERY with nulls in the exception block and good values after the exception block, I always get an empty set returned.
- If I have a flag that gets set in the exception block and an IF statement s.t. one branch returns the NULLs per flag being set in the exception block and the other being the values that were passed in, I always get the empty set returned.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042840/unable-to-log-exception-into-a-table-in-postgresql) and I think it's close, but I think I'm missing something.

UPDATE:

The insert to the error_log table happens with this code.  The function is called by

`SELECT * FROM public.uf_test( in_col1 => 'test_text'::TEXT );`

So for example, it could fail because of a primary key violation.

Comment: 1) Does the `INSERT INTO public.error_log (func_name, stacked_dx) ...` happen? 2) How are you calling the function? **Add answers as update to quetion text**.